# Generating HTML DOM from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, dom

I need to generate HTML DOM from JSON. I am using angularJS.

I am fine with JSON parsing but not sure how to use 'xpath' element in JSON to build the DOM.

My JSON looks like this

```
{   "view" : [
            {
                "xpath" : "/html",              
                "tag" : "html",
                "id" : null,
                "text" : null
            },
            {
                "xpath" : "/html/head",             
                "tag" : "head",
                "id" : null,
                "text" : "\n"
            },
            {
                "xpath" : "/html/body",             
                "tag" : "body",
                "id" : null,
                "text" : "\n\n"
            },
            {
                "xpath" : "/html/body/div",         
                "tag" : "div",
                "id" : null,
                "text" : "\n"
            },
            {
                "xpath" : "/html/body/div/input[1]",                
                "tag" : "input",
                "id" : null,
                "text" : null
            }           
            ]}
```

Any suggestion/pointer will be helpful

thanks

Comment: `xpath` == `<a href='/html'>`?

Comment: Split it on the / and walk the array.

Comment: Generated elements has to be placed into DOM tree as per the XPATH e.g. **"xpath" : "/html/body/div/input[1]** requires an <input> element under <html><body><div><input /></div></body></html>

Comment: @epascarello - how to traverse xpath in Javascript or JQuery?

Comment: is this JSON format set in stone?

Comment: @Mark it will be dynamic - this is a sample.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, but I mean can you change the layout.  Right now it would seem to have lots of assumptions about placement of things within the DOM.  For example having two or more div elements inside of the body then having input element inside of a div, without it being hierarchical you are making assumptions about the placement of those.  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @Mark it can be that much complex.